# Display sample size with xlabels in a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe `table`

```
table
Out[12]: 
                                  Highly unlikely  Slightly unlikely  Neutral  Slightly likely  Highly likely
age_bin                                                                                                     
18-24                                         13                 18       27               19              1
25-44                                         33                 21       35               39             17
45-64                                          1                  3        2                5              0
```

I have used the following code to generate a stacked bar chart.

```
ax = table.div(table.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).mul(100.0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, cmap = 'Blues', fontsize=15, figsize = (8,8))
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], loc='upper right', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of total respondents', fontsize = 20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15, rotation=45)
plt.ylim(0,100)
```

[image: Stacked bar chart]

As can be observed from `table` that the sample sizes for each `age_bin` (obtained from summing the values in each row) are different. For example, the number of samples belonging to the `age_bin` 18-24 is (13+18+27+19+1) = 78. I want this 78 within parentheses to be displayed alongside its respective `xlabel` (which is 18-24) on the x-axis.

Comment: The easiest way is to make a list of labels and total values. `labels = ['{}:{}'.format(x, str(y)) for x,y in zip(table.age_bin.tolist(),table.sum(1).tolist())]`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly way to do this, you can format your `x-axis ticks`. `plt.xticks` receives a string as it's argument, and you passed in a tuple `(sum[0], sum[1], sum[2])`. Since it expects a string it tried to transform it to string using the tuple's `__str__` method which gave you got output you got. You probably want to do something like:

```py
sum = (78,148,11)
ax = table.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, cmap = 'Blues', fontsize=15, figsize = (8,8))
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], loc='upper right', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of total respondents', fontsize = 20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15, rotation=45)
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), ("18-24"+', \n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[0]),"25-44"+', \n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[1]),"45-64"+'\n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[2])))
plt.ylim(0,100)
```

**P.S.:** I saved your data as csv, not the table and that's how my last `column` looks different that yours(not sure why), but it doesn't matters as you just need to add a string using `format`.

```py
sum = [78,148,11]
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), ("18-24"+', \n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[0]),"25-44"+', \n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[1]),"45-64"+'\n(total = ${}$)'.format(sum[2])))
```

[image: OutputImage]

Just add another `column`in your table as sum of all this (whatever you want to display) and use that element accordingly to display in `x-ticks`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have upvoted, but the comment to my question is the solution I was looking for. It is fully generalised unlike yours.